# SoftLayer API version 3.x

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am working with a team on a Automation Provisioning program written in Python based on the SoftLayer API.  The base program was written on an outdate SL API version 3.x.

The program is up and running and its only being used to run some tests.  We are debating if its worth the effort to update the program against the SL API 5.x.

Can anyone speak to any tangible benefits to going from SL API 3.x to 5.x.  For example we may be provisioning a thousand virtual servers with this program, would the latest API perform better?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The api versions are:

> **v3 and v3.1**

Did you refer [SoftLayer API Python Client 5.2.1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SoftLayer/5.2.1)?

Here the releases with its changes:: https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-python/releases

It's always better to have the last version from the client, but you can test if your program works fine with this version, if it doesn't, you can downgrade the version. Obviously the latest version provide more functionality and issues fixed. It shouldn't affect the provisionning process.

Comment: Hi Thanks, I actually did get it working under 5.2.1(CCI Manager was replaced with VS Manager) but if I can't point to any issue with the 3.x version I can't convince the team to apply the changes.

Comment: I believe if you will continue adding more stuffs, should be important to migrate to latest version. If you get any issue, feel free to post in order that find a solution or verify the issue